# Is a properly embedded submanifold of a submanifold of M properly embedded in M?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $P$ be the subset of $R^n$ with all positive components, $Q$ be the subset of $R^{n-1}$ with all positive components and $R$ be the strictly positive reals. Suppose $f:D \rightarrow R$ is smooth (say $C^1$), where $D$ is some open subset of $Q$: Then we know (say from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds 5.7) that the graph of $f$, $\Gamma \equiv \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})), (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) \in D \}$ is a proper, embedded submanifold of the open (sub) manifold $D \times R \subset Q \times R = P$.

I'm trying to find conditions under which $\Gamma$ is also a proper, embedded submanifold of $P$. I believe that to show properness I can require $\Gamma$ be closed in $P$, and I can show that by requiring, for every sequence $\{ x_n \} \in D$ which approaches a point $x^*$ which is in the boundary of $D$ but *not* in the boundary of $P$, that $\{ f(x_n) \}$ increases to $\infty$. I'm not sure about how to approach the embedded aspect.

Any comments on my approach so far and/or how to prove $\Gamma$ is embedded in $P$ would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the composition of two embeddings is an embedding. Also, if $f$ and $g$ are proper, and if $K$ is a compact set, then $(f\circ g)^{-1}(K) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(K))$ is...

Comment: @Didier: Oooh, I love hints, thank you. Let me see how far I can take this.

Comment: I've looked at this with the aid of your hint, and the (in retrospect) simple idea that the composition of two embeddings is an embedding seems to do the trick. However, from a properness standpoint, I don't see why my idea of showing the graph is closed in P is wrong (not saying it isn't just don't see it). Also, I'm not sure how to carry your properness hint forward as I would think the behavior at a point on the boundary of D but in the interior of P needs to come in somewhere, somehow and I can't see how to do this. Sorry if I'm being really dense.